# Auto load mp4 video to browser cache.

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to load a mp4 video from server to my browser cache and after full video is loaded to the browser cache,then play it with the HTML5 video tag. Is it posible ?

Comment: you should be able to find the answer here:
http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html
but I'm not sure all browsers will allow download of a video if it's not on the page, that's what "buffering" is for, and it works really well, it's built into the API.

Comment: additionally, your users may not want to have a full video downloaded if they do not intend to watch it all... again this is the realm of buffering and I'd recommend using it! :) you can set `autoplay` to `true`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-media-autoplay

"The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, the user agent (as described in the algorithm described herein) will _automatically begin playback of the media resource as soon as it can do so without stopping_."